# How can I can write pass multiple values with only one input tag?

Tags: php, html

I have an Html file like that

```
<form action="info.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="MyName"/>
</form>
```

and that is how my php file looks like

```
$MyName = $_GET['MyName'];
if(!isset($_GET['number'])) $number = 20;
else $number = $_GET['number'];
```

I want to pass two values MyName and number but I want to send number=10 always without editing php at all

Thank you all

Comment: Why dont you want to edit the php? Its the obvious thing to do, if you want to change the default from 20 to 10.

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="number" value="10" />  is that what you are looking for? Try it so you know what it means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can place an hidden input inside the form:

```
<form action="info.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="MyName"/>
<input type="hidden" name="number" value="10"/>
</form>
```

Comment: @user3880907 if it works consider marking this as answer

Answer (score 1):

You can send number using two ways

```
<form action="info.php?number=10" method="get">
```

OR

Create a hidden field for it

```
<input type="hidden" name="number" value="10"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="hidden" value="10"/>
```

Simple Solution to this problem is you  can add a hidden input Tag and set the value of input tag to 10.This is the simple solution to problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use a hidden field.

```
<input type="hidden" value="10" name="number" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to pass multiple values from one input only
use

```
<input type="hidden" value="10" name="number1 10 15" />
```

In backend for nodejs

```
for key in req.body:
   [number, number2 number3] = key.split(" ");
```